# Using mailcore2 from cocoapod in SWIFT 2

Tags: ios, swift2, mailcore2, xcode7.3

I'm using mailcore2 in my project with SWIFT 2 and I made everything about installation, create pod file , updating pod file , creating header at the correct path , change it at Build setting but when I'm trying to import mailcore2 in my controller-view it gives me this error :

[image]

This picture for the tree of my project
[image]

What is the problem in this case if I made everything correctly !

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution by removing import from the controller because I recognize that after reading these lines 
[image]